# Deep Water Weapons/Vehicles

Tags: warfare, weapons, underwater, water, ocean

Edit: The original question had too many offshoots and was too broad. I hope this new question is better formatted.

I am working on a concept where Earth is unintentionally "invaded" by aliens from an ocean world. Their technology relies entirely on bioengineering and genetic manipulation. The enemy "force" consists of engineered organisms - all entirely organic.

Would modified deep sea dive suits, such as the [Navy's ADS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_diving_suit), be preferable to traditional submarines against creatures which could potentially latch onto the hull?

Comment: It seems like you're looking for us to do your brainstorming for you. That isn't the purpose of this site.

Comment: Just use [giant robots](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1663662/).

Comment: Welcome. It looks like you have done the same mistake I did. Put all the 'related' questions on what you consider 1 question (weapons) in one post. Currently you are asking 4 major questions with plenty of offshoots. Rather try focus each post on a specific question, that way you can get focused and more detailed answers. Unfortunately, currently this is way to broad and would likely get put on hold. You can edit this question to focus on just one and provide more of your details/thinking (so that we don't do all the brainstorming for you), or you can start a new one/s. enjoy and good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I apologize for not being focused enough, it was a noobie mistake. I don't think I'd be able to rewrite the question in this single post, so it might be better for me to scrub it and try again.

Comment: The comment above provides good advice.  I would also just add that you should check out the [help].  It has a good general overview on writing good questions and answers.  Welcome to the site Dave.

Comment: Good job editing your question down to one core theme. This is still a pretty broad question. Try narrowing down the scope a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Water is fairly incompressible. Use it at your advantage. Bombs deal a big shock wave which travels well in water.

If you want to go big, underwater nukes are your choice.

Comment: Exactly what was going to say. I think there are even nuclear-tipped torpedos too.